# Incorrect alignment when using aligned

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, align

I'm trying to TeX some nice equations but there is a strange behaviour when I use an `aligned`-environment in an `align*`-environment. I think one little example makes my problem clear:

```
\begin{align*}
& A \land \\
& \begin{aligned}
B = & B1 \land \\
    & B2
\end{aligned} \\
\Longrightarrow \;& what follows from A \land B
\end{align*}
```

When I compile this A and B are not equal aligned. It seems like the beginning of the `aligned`-environment produces a little space. Any idea?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Could you perhaps provide what exactly you're after? There may be better ways of doing what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the "A" in the first row and the "B" in the second row to line up by insering a "thinspace", `\,`, in front of "A". Incidentally, in the second row it's preferable to write `&=` rather than `=&` in order to get the typographically appropriate amount of spacing around the `=` symbol.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
& \,A \land \\
& \begin{aligned}
   B &=  B1 \land \\
   &\phantom{{}={}} B2
\end{aligned} \\
\Longrightarrow &\text{ what follows from A $\land$ B}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```